# Anbox Android emulator does not work in 22.10

Tags: android, 22.10, anbox

I want to install the proprietary game Geometry Dash Lite on my computer as an APK file.
In order to run APK files in Ubuntu, I need an emulator called Anbox and it luckily is on the repository. I installed it via the Synaptic Package Manager. It opens up to a point where it shows the "Starting..." and it eventually closes. I have had this issue for many months and I cannot find an answer. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Christopher

[image]